# What is the best way in ES6 to assign a constant conditionally?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I would like to assign to my `const validation` a value based on a condition.

If `this.showRequired() == true`
Then it should be `'required'`

Else if `this.showError() == true`
Then it should be `'error'`.

I know of course that I could extract it to a function, or cascade ternary operators, but the first seems code bloat, the latter ugly.

Is there a better way to do it? If-else expressions maybe?

Comment: What is wrong with ternary operators? They are the much more concise *expression* form of if-else.

Comment: IMO the syntax is a bit cryptic. I prefer Scala's if-else expressions.

Comment: @Midiparse You may need to make this adjustment. Ternary operators are very common in Javascript. If you plan to read open-source code, or make contributions, it will be helpful to understand them at a glance.

Comment: I second @Midiparse. If a ternary is nested, I would avoid it at all costs. Single-condition ternary expressions are fine and can be quite clean if the condition and expressions are simple enough.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Cascading ternary operator looks fine for me:

```
const validation = this.showRequired() ? 'required' : this.showError() ? 'error' : null
```

If you think this line is too long, you could split it:

```
const validation = this.showRequired() ? 'required'
                   : this.showError() ? 'error'
                   : null
```

Or you could use `&&` and `||` instead:

```
const validation = (this.showRequired() && 'required') ||
                   (this.showError() && 'error')
```

As for extacting this code into a separate function, you could always use an inline function instead of creating yet another class method:

```
const validation = (() => {
  if (this.showRequired()) {
    return 'required'
  } else if (this.showError()) {
    return 'error'
  }
})()
```

But ternary operator looks better anyway, especially if it's split into several lines.

Comment: Honestly, I would avoid the ternary if there is more than one condition. For that, I don't actually mind the inline function. It's much clearer and allows you to use a `const` instead of a `let`.

Comment: In fact eslint by default, flags nested ternaries